# File is only written in debug mode

Tags: c#, debugging, file-io, process

I have a strange issue. I wrote some code which should merge first names and last names into a csv-file.

As long as I execute the program in debug mode (I am using c# / .NET as language), the file is correctly generated and filled up. But as soon as I simply start the program, the program does not finish. Additionally, the file created is not filled. I can see in the windows explorer that the file is accessed all the time the program is running.

I tried things like "Environment.Exit(0);" or "return", but nothing helped so far. The problem might be stupid and easily solved, though I am not getting a solution for it :( ..

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!!

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] nachname = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\NameUndVorname\NameUndVorname\obj\Debug\name.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
            string[] vorname = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\NameUndVorname\NameUndVorname\obj\Debug\vorname.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
        int zaehler = 0;
        int zaehlerwhile = 0;
        int nachnamezaehler = 0;

        int laengenachname = nachname.Length;
        int laengevorname = vorname.Length;
        string[] NachnameUndVornamen = new string[laengenachname * laengevorname];

        while (zaehlerwhile < laengevorname)
        {
            NachnameUndVornamen[zaehler] = vorname[zaehlerwhile] + nachname[nachnamezaehler];
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\NameUndVorname\NameUndVorname\obj\Debug\nameundvorname.csv"))
            {
                file.Write(string.Join(";", NachnameUndVornamen));
            }
            zaehler++;
            nachnamezaehler++;

            if (nachnamezaehler == laengenachname) {
                zaehlerwhile++;
                nachnamezaehler = 0;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your code in a static method outside of main function.
Call that function insid static void Main(string[] args) as

```
public static void ProcessData()
{
    

    string[] nachname = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\NameUndVorname\NameUndVorname\obj\Debug\name.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
    string[] vorname = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\NameUndVorname\NameUndVorname\obj\Debug\vorname.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
int zaehler = 0;
int zaehlerwhile = 0;
int nachnamezaehler = 0;

int laengenachname = nachname.Length;
int laengevorname = vorname.Length;
string[] NachnameUndVornamen = new string[laengenachname * laengevorname];

while (zaehlerwhile < laengevorname)
{
    NachnameUndVornamen[zaehler] = vorname[zaehlerwhile] + nachname[nachnamezaehler];
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\NameUndVorname\NameUndVorname\obj\Debug\nameundvorname.csv"))
    {
        file.Write(string.Join(";", NachnameUndVornamen));
    }
    zaehler++;
    nachnamezaehler++;

    if (nachnamezaehler == laengenachname) {
        zaehlerwhile++;
        nachnamezaehler = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Now simply call it in main function as:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessData();
        }
    }
}
```